# How can I catch an AccessViolationException in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, shutdown

When our (Out Of Browser) Silverlight application is shut down by the user, we sometimes get an AccessViolationException when trying to write to a log file (on a separate thread). It appears that the Silverlight runtime is shutting down and not expecting IO operations to take place during the shutdown sequence.

Trying to catch the AccessViolationException and ignore it does not appear to be working, even when the method is decorated with the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions required to catch that and other exceptions that represent really nasty errors.

Is there some even more powerful way of catching an exception or at least hiding it from the user?

Comment: You can't handle AV, the thread is dead.  Fix the real problem.

Comment: @Hans, the "real problem" is Silverlight. I'm not sure what it's doing at shutdown, but whatever it is - it should not throw a nasty exception like that.

Comment: please can you post your code which performs logging? Looks like you're trying to add log to a file which already opened for writing.

Comment: @Igor, we're using NLog, logging to the same file during the entire lifetime of the application. (Elevated Trust, Out Of Browser, which lets us write to files in certain locations without having to prompt the user.) The log call causing the problem is no different from the others other than in that it is executed during shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar situation. When the user would exit the app the AccessViolationException would get thrown. The cause was I had code still doing work on a background thread and that code would log (using NLog).

Eventually NLog winds up trying to create a FileStream while silverlight runtime is shutting down which causes the error.

If you turn on break when an exception is thrown in visual studio (ctrl+alt+e) it helps to pinpoint.

Once I had this figured out to fix I had to make sure to stop all my background threads before allowing the app to exit. This was not too bad for me, since I was using MEF i could just dispose the container and implement IDisposable where needed.